# i am making a discord currency bot and get the same key error all the time

Tags: python, keyerror

```
@slash.slash(name="Balance", description="check your current balance")
async def balance(ctx):
    open_account(ctx.author)
with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
if str(ctx.author.id) in users:
    return False

else:
    users[str(ctx.author.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(ctx.author.id)]["bank"] = 0

with open("mainbank.json") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
return users
```

and i keep getting this error:

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `balance`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\model.py", line 210, in invoke
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\funbot.py", line 74, in balance
    users[str(ctx.author.id)]["wallet"] = 0
KeyError: '370972899818995713'
```

Comment: So, it appears that `ctx.author.id` is not within `users`; so, what's actually in `users`? Is it maybe stored as an integer and not a string? Does just `users[ctx.author.id]` work?

Comment: I just tried it but it didnt work

Comment: Okay but that was just a suggestion. The main point of my comment, which you ignored, was that we need to know what's in `users` if you want there to be any chance of us helping you.

Comment: i just checked and its currently empty. plus sorry i am like 13 so and in a hurry so i didnt read so precisly